# Black ioslides, any ideas?

Tags: r, markdown, ioslides

Does anyone know of a way to diagnose why my ioslides presentation is knitting but returning a series of blank/black. I have no sample data. Just hoping that someone has encountered this issue before. My only guess is that it has to do with the YAML. My YAML at present is this

```
  ---
  title: Nevada Labor Market Briefing
  subtitle: <span style="font-size:22px; font-family:'Arial'; color:#0A0A0A;3 font- 
  weight:normal">May 2022</span><br></br>
   author: <span style="font-size:18px; font-family:'Arial'; color:#0A0A0A; float:left; font- 
   weight:normal">Research and Analysis</span>
  date: <span style="font-size:18px; font-family:'Arial'; color:#0A0A0A;font-style:normal; 
  float:left">6/16/2022</span>
   output: 
   ioslides_presentation:
css: styles.css
logo: state.png
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I deleted all of the packages in my win library and reinstalled all of them. Upon doing so, it told me that to knit new documents, I needed a new version of markdown. From there, i restarted my computer.